# How return result of a function with tkinter messagebox

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to write code that will return either head or tails and show it in a separate window (message box). How can I show the result of my function in a separate window (message box)?

```
import tkinter
import numpy as np
from tkinter import messagebox

result = []

def hola():

    coin = np.random.randint(0,2)
    if coin == 0:
       result.append("heads")
    else:
       result.append("tails")
    messagebox.showinfo( "Lucky you !", result )

top = tkinter.Tk()
B = tkinter.Button(top, text ="flip da coin", command = hola)

B.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this;

```
import tkinter
import numpy as np
from tkinter import messagebox

def hola():

    coin = np.random.randint(0,2)
    if coin == 0:
       result = "heads"
    else:
       result = "tails"
    messagebox.showinfo( "Lucky you !", result )

top = tkinter.Tk()
B = tkinter.Button(top, text ="flip da coin", command = hola)

B.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: you don't need global variable `result = ""` because `hola()` uses local variable `result`

Comment: Thank you! It finally works. Also, sorry for my grammar and thank you for fixing it. English is not my first language, so when I am unconcentrated I can make lots of mistakes.